# Android Wear 5.1 wrist gesture API?

Tags: android, wear-os

Android 5.1.1 for wearables introduced the ability to dimiss notifications by rotating/flicking your wrist.  Is this API exposed for developers to use? I'm unable to find any information on this, and their wearables developer site does not seem to have been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a bit late but [this](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/gestures.html#using_key_events) looks like what you exactly wanted.

Although pushing, raising, shaking gesture is not available, flicking wrist out and in gesture is available.

> Each wrist gesture is mapped to an int constant from the KeyEvent class, as shown in the following table:
>
> Flick wrist out: KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT, This key code goes to the next item.
>
> Flick wrist in: KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_PREVIOUS, This key code goes to the previous item.

You can handle the event like this: (example code from developer document)

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  switch (keyCode) {
   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT:
    // Do something that advances a user View to the next item in an ordered list.
    return moveToNextItem();
   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_PREVIOUS:
    // Do something that advances a user View to the previous item in an ordered list.
    return moveToPreviousItem();
  }
  // If you did not handle it, let it be handled by the next possible element as deemed by the Activity.
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Comment: This does indeed seem to fit the bill - not sure why you were downvoted.  I'll change the answer to you as the previously-accepted one is now out of date.

Comment: What does the comment   //Do something that advances a user View to the next item in an ordered list.   mean?  Could someone provide a code example of a user View in an ordered list?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is currently no wrist gesture API for Wear 1.0 devices and that is why the developer site does not mention wrist gestures.

Comment: Generally Google does not talk about upcoming functionality, but they haven't made any comments on wrist gestures either way.